# What is the actual use of Tree in Java

Tags: java, tree

I am using the Java Tree from collection but what will be the actual use of Tree.
As in CS language, a B-tree can have a max of 2 childs , leaf , height of the tree and other.
But in java how these interpretation can be observed and what is the implementation of Tree in java.

I am talking about TreeMap and TreeSet only

Comment: Which Tree class are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the `TreeSet` and `TreeMap` classes, they are implementing the `Set` and `Map` interfaces respectively with an internal representation of a Tree structure.  So the tree inside is not accessible to users (you cannot access the children directly)

*Note*: there is no standard `Tree` interface in java

Comment: what is then the actual importance of using Tree DS in Map and Set

Comment: @bunta: They offer certain time complexities for insert/lookup/etc.

Comment: @bunta - So they are optimized for fast insertion and lookup while keeping the elements sorted (actually they also implement the `SortedSet` and `SortedMap` interfaces)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a `Tree` - are you sure you don't mean either `TreeSet` or `TreeMap`?

Either way, both of these use [Red-Black Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) as the underlying implementation.

Apart from having the performance characteristics of Red-Black trees ( O(log(n)) time for most common operations), they otherwise behave in pretty much the same way as `HashSet` and `HashMap` - in most cases you can use them interchangeably.